# Logging PDO exception to error_reporting and error_log

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, error-handling, error-reporting

Currently my script is able to display PDO exception on the browser but it is not logging to error file. I would rather like to turn off the browser error message using **display_errors** and log it to a file using **error_log** instead. I don't know if it's possible or if I need to write some custom handler or it's being overridden by framework. Here is my log configuration in my virtualhost. Note that it's logging all other error messages well including notices. But it is not logging PDO exceptions. Any ideas?

I think you can ignore the value the of display_errors of my virtualhost configuration.

```
    php_admin_flag log_errors on
    php_admin_flag display_errors on
    php_admin_value error_reporting 30719
    php_admin_value error_log "/....PATH/php.error.log"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I need to override the exception handler which is independent from error handler. So I need to forward the exceptions to error handler. Theoretically, the following should be implemented.

```
<?php
function exception_handler($exception) {
  echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
  error_log(.....$exception->getMessage().....); //Yay it goes to my file now
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

throw new Exception('Uncaught Exception');
echo "Not Executed\n";
?>
```

[Research further here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php)